Problem Injecting DLL into Vipasana Ransomware
I wanted to hook RegQueryValue and WriteFile functions called by Vipasana ransomware using a dll injected by VirtualAlloxEx, WriteProcessMemory and then CreateRemoteThread. I have applied error handling methods too as can be seen in the code. I have tried for other processes, and it works perfectly fine for those. But when I try to inject into the Vipasana ransomware process, nothing happens. Not even the error messages are printed. The commandline screen is just completely blank.
// Function to inject DLL into a process
bool InjectDLL(DWORD processID, const char* dllPath) {
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    if (hProcess == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open process: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    LPVOID pLoadLibrary = (LPVOID)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (pLoadLibrary == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Could not find LoadLibrary function: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return false;
    }

    LPVOID pRemoteMemory = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, strlen(dllPath) + 1, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (pRemoteMemory == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Could not allocate memory in remote process: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return false;
    }

    else std::cout << "Virtual Memory Address: " << pRemoteMemory << std::endl;

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pRemoteMemory, (LPVOID)dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, NULL)) {
        std::cerr << "Could not write to process memory: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return false;
    }

    HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)pLoadLibrary, pRemoteMemory, 0, NULL);
    if (hThread == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Could not create remote thread: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
        return false;
    }

    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);

    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, pRemoteMemory, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return true;
}


I think you forgot to attach the image.

Apologies, I forgot to delete that line before posting. There is actually nothing to show in the image, its just nothing. I tried debugging, it looks like Vipasana Ransomware is hooking into CreateRemoteThread or NtCreateThreadEx (I tried using both) or doing something else (I don't understand what) to prevent either of the APIs from executing when they have the ransomware's handle. Before that, everything was executing just as it was intended to.
